# Change order of name column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have a table customer with a column as 'Name' with customer names as its value. One example of that column value is 'Aditya, Narayan'. But I want the name to be 'Narayan, Aditya'. How to do that in an oracle SQL developer query?
P.S. I cannot paste the image of the table as company policy.

Comment: You don't need to include your real data, but you can include more made-up but representative sample values (as formatted text, not an image). Do the names always have a comma (and a space); and can there be more than one word in each part - how would Sarah Jessica Parker or Kristin Scott Thomas appear, to pick two examples at random?

Comment: @AlexPoole I am sorry for not mentioning it but the columns have some values that don't have comma in it and also the names which have has only first name and last name, no middle name.

Answer (score 2):

Two simple options include `substr + instr` combination (`new_name_1`) or regular expressions (`new_name_2` and `new_name_3`).

```
SQL> with customer (name) as
  2    (select 'Aditya,Narayan' from dual union all
  3     select 'Little,Foot'    from dual
  4    )
  5  select name,
  6    --
  7    substr(name, instr(name, ',') + 1) ||','|| substr(name, 1, instr(name, ',') - 1) new_name_1,
  8    --
  9    regexp_substr(name, '\w+$') ||','|| regexp_substr(name, '^\w+') new_name_2,
 10    --
 11    regexp_replace(name, '(.*),(.*)', '\2,\1') new_name_3
 12  from customer;

NAME           NEW_NAME_1           NEW_NAME_2           NEW_NAME_3
-------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Aditya,Narayan Narayan,Aditya       Narayan,Aditya       Narayan,Aditya
Little,Foot    Foot,Little          Foot,Little          Foot,Little

SQL>
```